# Double output from mysql. I wonder what I am doing wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a double output from mysql. I am using a resource for the columns and another for the rows, and a for loop.

```
function selectItems($table)
{
    $resultado='';
    $select_resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_fields($select_resource);

    for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($select_resource);  

        foreach($result as $key=>$var)
        {
            $resultado .="$key: $var<br/>\n";
        }

        $resultado .="<hr />";
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

This is the test

```
$data = new Db();
$data->connect(HOST, USER, DB, PASSWORD);
echo $data->selectItems("comments");
$data->closeDb();
```

And this is the output

```
/*
0: 1
id: 1
1: name
username: name
2: Content
comment: Content
3: 000.000.000.000
ip: 000.000.000.000
4: Itâ€™s impressive how popular content management i
title: Itâ€™s impressive how popular content management i
5: freemind
avatar: freemind
*/
```

Comment: I solved it by fetching row instead of array.  I also changed the number of fields for the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), the default is to fetch both the numeric and the associative array.

If you want just *one* of them, add a second parameter to your `mysql_fetch_array()` call, such as:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($select_resource,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

And be aware, you're actually storing the number of *columns* in your `num_rows` variable. You should be using [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

This line is crucial `$result = mysql_fetch_array($select_resource);`

You could use `mysql_fetch_assoc($select_resource)` and that's it.

Another thing is that `mysql_num_rows` would be more appropriate. It would pull all the data.  In your case it will lack one record, sadly.

I would suggest you to *switch to MySQLi, or PDO of course* but in your case this is a correct solution.